# Pass action to the app when the user click on notification on android devices

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

How can I pass information to the android application when a user click notification when the application not in foreground, for example the user get a message, he notice it be getting a notification, after the user click it he navigate to the application, the problem is that the application opens in the default state, I want to navigate to the messaging page first.

```
public class MyGcmListenerService extends GcmListenerService {

private static final String TAG = "MyGcmListenerService";
private UserDetails userDetails;

/**
 * Called when message is received.
 *
 * @param from SenderID of the sender.
 * @param data Data bundle containing message data as key/value pairs.
 *             For Set of keys use data.keySet().
 */
// [START receive_message]
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
    String message = data.getString("message");
    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + from);
    Log.d(TAG, "Message: " + message);
    Log.d(TAG, "Data" + data);

    /**
     * In some cases it may be useful to show a notification indicating to the user
     * that a message was received.
     */
    if(isAppOnForeground()){
        //Toast.makeText(getApplication(), data.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else{
        sendNotification(message);
        return;
        //sendNotification("You are not in the app");
    }

}

/**
 * Create and show a simple notification containing the received GCM message.
 *
 * @param message GCM message received.
 */
private void sendNotification(String message) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.two_grow_icon)
            .setContentTitle("Test")
            .setContentText(message)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
}

//Function that check if the application in foreground
private boolean isAppOnForeground() {
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> appProcesses = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
    if (appProcesses == null) {
        return false;
    }
    final String packageName = getPackageName();
    for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo appProcess : appProcesses) {
        if (appProcess.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND && appProcess.processName.equals(packageName)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: please. provide us a code of your notification builder.

Comment: The answer to your question will depend on the type of message you are sending, notification message or data message. Please include your request to GCM in your question. From the code that you do have though your notification has an intent that goes to MainActivity which I will assume is your "default state" try changing that.